# Dismissible listener so that animation can be shown

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using `Dismissible` and I would like to set up a listener for this, so that I can animate my background widget (an `Icon`) just like Gmail app does.

I can't find any listener that listens for the position of the dragged card in `Dismissible`.

[image]